# WiFi gets unusable when using Bluetooth (21.10)

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, bluetooth, 21.10

**Notebook HP 14-am004la (2016) Intel Celeron N3060** (Very low spec machine)

I recently got my hands around installing the bluetooth drivers for my laptop. Ever since I installed the OS a year ago I just didn't need to use bluetooth, now I need to use it for something important.

I supposedly installed the latest WiFi and Bluetooth drivers, but it doesn't work.

When I turn on Bluetooth and pair a device it goes well and all until I try to browse the internet via Wifi. It took 15 minutes to open speedtest.net when normally it would've taken like 20 seconds when Bluetooth was off (the connection is ok on my other devices).

Is there any way to fix this?

I need to use both and don't have access to an Ethernet connection.

What I have according to lshw:

```
 *-cpu
      description: CPU
      product: Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU  N3060  @ 1.60GHz
      vendor: Intel Corp.
      physical id: 4
      bus info: cpu@0
      version: Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU  N3060  @ 1.60GHz
      serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
      slot: CHV
      size: 2258MHz
      capacity: 2480MHz
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 83MHz
      capabilities: lm fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes rdrand lahf_lm 3dnowprefetch epb pti ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid tsc_adjust smep erms dtherm ida arat md_clear cpufreq
      configuration: cores=2 enabledcores=2 threads=2
    

      *-core
           description: Motherboard
           product: 81E1
           vendor: HP
           physical id: 0
           version: KBC Version 71.17
           serial: PFXFE00WB257PO
           slot: Type2 - Board Chassis Location
         *-firmware
              description: BIOS
              vendor: Insyde
              physical id: 0
              version: F.36
              date: 01/06/2020
              size: 64KiB
              capacity: 3MiB
              capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int9keyboard int14serial int17printer int10video acpi usb zipboot biosbootspecification netboot uefi}


*-network
                        description: Wireless interface
                        product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
                        vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
                        physical id: 0
                        bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                        logical name: wlp2s0
                        version: 01
                        serial: 44:1c:a8:93:cb:6b
                        width: 64 bits
                        clock: 33MHz
                        capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                        configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) ip=10.1.131.125 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
                        resources: irq:18 memory:91200000-91207fff
```

Stuff requested by heynnema:

```
dkms status:
    bcmwl, 6.30.223.271+bdcom, 5.13.0-37-generic, x86_64: installed
    rtbth, 3.9.7, 5.13.0-35-generic, x86_64: installed
    rtbth, 3.9.7, 5.13.0-37-generic, x86_64: installed

lsmod | grep -i bcm    
         btbcm                  20480  1 btusb
         bluetooth             663552  43   btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm

lsmod
    Module                  Size  Used by
    ccm                    20480  6
    rtl8xxxu              139264  0
    mac80211             1024000  1 rtl8xxxu
    libarc4                16384  1 mac80211
    rfcomm                 81920  16
    nft_fib_inet           16384  1
    nft_fib_ipv4           16384  1 nft_fib_inet
    nft_fib_ipv6           16384  1 nft_fib_inet
    nft_fib                16384  3 nft_fib_ipv6,nft_fib_ipv4,nft_fib_inet
    nft_reject_inet        16384  4
    nf_reject_ipv4         16384  1 nft_reject_inet
    nf_reject_ipv6         20480  1 nft_reject_inet
    nft_reject             16384  1 nft_reject_inet
    nft_ct                 20480  8
    nft_chain_nat          16384  4
    nf_nat                 49152  1 nft_chain_nat
    nf_conntrack          151552  2 nf_nat,nft_ct
    nf_defrag_ipv6         24576  1 nf_conntrack
    nf_defrag_ipv4         16384  1 nf_conntrack
    ip_set                 53248  0
    nf_tables             212992  220 nft_ct,nft_reject_inet,nft_fib_ipv6,nft_fib_ipv4,nft_chain_nat,nft_reject,nft_fib,nft_fib_inet
    libcrc32c              16384  3 nf_conntrack,nf_nat,nf_tables
    nfnetlink              20480  3 nf_tables,ip_set
    cmac                   16384  3
    algif_hash             16384  1
    algif_skcipher         16384  1
    af_alg                 28672  6 algif_hash,algif_skcipher
    bnep                   28672  2
    nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
    snd_hda_codec_hdmi     65536  1
    snd_ctl_led            24576  0
    snd_hda_codec_realtek   147456  1
    snd_hda_codec_generic    81920  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
    ledtrig_audio          16384  2 snd_ctl_led,snd_hda_codec_generic
    mei_hdcp               24576  0
    intel_rapl_msr         20480  0
    snd_hda_intel          53248  3
    snd_intel_dspcfg       28672  1 snd_hda_intel
    snd_intel_sdw_acpi     20480  1 snd_intel_dspcfg
    snd_hda_codec         147456  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
    snd_hda_core           94208  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek
    snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
    intel_powerclamp       20480  0
    coretemp               20480  0
    kvm_intel             290816  0
    kvm                   880640  1 kvm_intel
    punit_atom_debug       16384  0
    crct10dif_pclmul       16384  1
    ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
    snd_pcm               118784  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
    snd_seq_midi           20480  0
    aesni_intel           376832  8
    btusb                  61440  0
    btrtl                  24576  1 btusb
    btbcm                  20480  1 btusb
    btintel                32768  1 btusb
    snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
    crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
    bluetooth             663552  43 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
    snd_rawmidi            36864  1 snd_seq_midi
    cryptd                 24576  3 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel
    intel_cstate           20480  0
    uvcvideo              106496  0
    i915                 2437120  8
    videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  1 uvcvideo
    videobuf2_memops       20480  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
    snd_seq                73728  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
    videobuf2_v4l2         32768  1 uvcvideo
    videobuf2_common       61440  4 videobuf2_vmalloc,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_memops
    joydev                 28672  0
    input_leds             16384  0
    ecdh_generic           16384  2 bluetooth
    snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
    ecc                    36864  1 ecdh_generic
    videodev              249856  3 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
    snd_timer              40960  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
    hp_wmi                 20480  0
    platform_profile       16384  1 hp_wmi
    sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
    serio_raw              20480  0
    drm_kms_helper        262144  1 i915
    mc                     57344  4 videodev,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
    wmi_bmof               16384  0
    efi_pstore             16384  0
    cfg80211              897024  2 mac80211,rtl8xxxu
    at24                   24576  0
    snd                    94208  18 snd_ctl_led,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
    processor_thermal_device    20480  0
    cec                    53248  2 drm_kms_helper,i915
    processor_thermal_rfim    16384  1 processor_thermal_device
    mei_txe                28672  1
    processor_thermal_mbox    16384  1 processor_thermal_device
    mei                   131072  3 mei_hdcp,mei_txe
    rc_core                57344  1 cec
    soundcore              16384  2 snd_ctl_led,snd
    i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
    fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
    processor_thermal_rapl    20480  1 processor_thermal_device
    syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
    intel_xhci_usb_role_switch    16384  0
    sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
    intel_rapl_common      24576  2 intel_rapl_msr,processor_thermal_rapl
    sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
    intel_soc_dts_iosf     20480  1 processor_thermal_device
    soc_button_array       20480  0
    intel_int0002_vgpio    16384  1
    mac_hid                16384  0
    int3400_thermal        20480  0
    hp_wireless            16384  0
    acpi_thermal_rel       16384  1 int3400_thermal
    int3403_thermal        20480  0
    int340x_thermal_zone    20480  2 int3403_thermal,processor_thermal_device
    sch_fq_codel           20480  6
    ipmi_devintf           20480  0
    ipmi_msghandler       114688  1 ipmi_devintf
    msr                    16384  0
    parport_pc             45056  0
    ppdev                  24576  0
    lp                     20480  0
    parport                65536  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev
    drm                   561152  6 drm_kms_helper,i915
    ip_tables              32768  0
    x_tables               49152  1 ip_tables
    autofs4                45056  2
    psmouse               159744  0
    crc32_pclmul           16384  0
    i2c_i801               36864  0
    i2c_smbus              20480  1 i2c_i801
    lpc_ich                24576  0
    r8169                  94208  0
    realtek                32768  1
    ahci                   40960  2
    libahci                36864  1 ahci
    xhci_pci               24576  0
    xhci_pci_renesas       20480  1 xhci_pci
    wmi                    32768  2 hp_wmi,wmi_bmof
    video                  53248  1 i915

modinfo rtl8xxxu | grep -i parm
    parm:           debug:Set debug mask (int)
    parm:           ht40_2g:Enable HT40 support on the 2.4GHz band (bool)
    parm:           dma_aggregation:Enable DMA packet aggregation (bool)
    parm:           dma_agg_timeout:Set DMA aggregation timeout (range 1-127) (int)
    parm:           dma_agg_pages:Set DMA aggregation pages (range 1-127, 0 to disable) (int)

ls -al /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/updates/dkms
total 7492
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 mar 29 13:50 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    4096 mar 29 00:26 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  142765 mar 29 00:26 rtbth.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 7516933 mar 29 13:50 wl.ko

modinfo wl | grep -i parm
    parm:           passivemode:int
    parm:           wl_txq_thresh:int
    parm:           oneonly:int
    parm:           piomode:int
    parm:           instance_base:int
    parm:           nompc:int
    parm:           intf_name:string
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135163/discussion-on-question-by-rick-afk-wifi-gets-unusable-when-using-bluetooth-21-1).

Answer (score 0):

This is possible to fix. You have an Intel adapter.

Run

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=N"
```

and reboot.

The setting can be reverted by

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf
```